# SVN Pre-commit hook to be triggered for a particular folder

Tags: php, svn, pre-commit-hook, phpcodesniffer

One of our client's SVN repository has quite a bunch of projects under the single repository. Now I want to check coding-standard for one of the project via pre-commit hook.

If I configure the pre-commit, it is going to affect all the projects (folders) in the repository, how do I tell the hook-script to trigger (check the coding standard) only when a file from a particular folder (or project) is committed.

**UPDATE**

The coding standard is intentional for Zend and I am going to use [PHPCS (PHP Coding Standard)](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.svn-pre-commit.php)  to validate the coding-standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `svnlook` in the pre-commit to see the paths changed, and if the path contains the project you are considering, do the coding standards etc.

You can use the `dirs-changed` subcommand (and the `--transaction` flag):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnlook.c.dirs-changed.html

Or the `changed` subcommand:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html

Example of a pre-commit using svnlook: http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

Comment: Looks like this should work. I will have to use `grep` to see the list.

Comment: Programmer..uh... finds a way

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The script needs to check all the affected paths (they can be more than one) and act accordingly.

Comment: @Alvaro-g-vicario don't say that, there should be some way.

Comment: @RakeshS - Of course there is: make your script check all the affected paths and act accordingly. See manojlds' answer for the exact details.

Comment: @RudolfMayer Not sure why someone who knows that two answers to a given question are wrong would leave a complaint comment in the non-accepted one rather sharing his knowledge in a proper answer. Meanwhile, I reassert my statement (you cannot configure Subversion to trigger hooks based on paths, you have to write a hook that runs *every time* and implements its own path filter logic) and I address to manojlds' excellent answer for some good hints on how to do it.